# Codeigniter autoloader isn't picking up cassandra library

Tags: php, codeigniter, cassandra

Hi I am new to cassandra database. I am downloaded phpcassa from 
https://github.com/mauritsl/php-cassandra.

When I tried to autoload cassandra library from application/config/autoload.php I got non existence class cassandra error.

Please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

o Place all Cassandra related files into application/library/ folder.

- Remove the name space from each Cassandra class file.

"namespace Cassandra;"

- Your file name and class name should match to load the library in auto load function in codeigniter.

Cassandra file class name is "Connection".

- Change the class name as "Cassandra"
- Your constructor expects a parameter to connect the database. You can't pass parameters while loading autoload library.
- Change your constructor method name as connect
- Using $this->cassandra->connect($host,$keyspace,$options) you can process the connection.

Rename the __construct into connect

```
/**
   * Connect to Cassandra cluster.
   *
   * @param mixed $host
   *   Hostname as string or array of hostnames.
   * @param string $keyspace
   * @param array $options
   */
  public function connect($host, $keyspace = NULL, $options = array()) {
    $this->options += $options;

    if (empty($host)) {
      throw new InvalidArgumentException('Invalid host');
    }
    if (!is_array($host)) {
      $host = array($host);
    }
    shuffle($host);
    while ($host) {
      $hostname = array_pop($host);
      try {
        $this->transport = new Transport($hostname, $this->options['connect_timeout'], $this->options['stream_timeout']);
        break;
      }
      catch (Exception $e) {
        if (empty($host)) {
          // No other hosts available, rethrow exception.
          throw $e;
        }
      }
    }
```